# Cordova wmic command Failed

Tags: linux, command-line, wmic, npm

I am working on windows 10 and when i am trying to create a cordova project i get the the following error thrown.The command used is :

```
cordova create weather-app

C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
            throw err;
            ^
```

Error: Command failed: wmic os get Caption
ERROR:
Description = Not found

```
at makeError (C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
at windowsRelease (C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:34:24)
at osName (C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
at new Insight (C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:26:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
```

{
  code: 2147749890,

stdout: '',

stderr: 'ERROR:\r\r\nDescription = Not found\r\r\n',

failed: true,

signal: null,

cmd: 'wmic os get Caption',

timedOut: false

}

If anyone had the same issue and found any work around please help.

Thank you

Comment: Why the Linux and npm tags?

Comment: Add extension? E.g. `wmic.exe os get Caption`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which I've fixed by changing line 37 of "...\insight\lib\index.js" (full file path is in the error message you posted).

From:

> this.os = osName();

To:

> this.os = '';

This file, together with telemetry.js, seem to be sending usage data to the developer's Google Analytics account.

It seems to be using a call to WMIC to get the operating system version. The WMIC OS command doesn't exist in my Windows 10 installation.